# HTML input type="number" browser behavior problems

Tags: html, floating-point

This is the first time I'm using input type="number".  The following is validated with mixed results depending on what browser I'm using.  Chrome works beautifully, validating both the regex and the min/max values.  IE and FF validate only the regex.  Worst of all, it seems that IE is rejecting the minus sign altogether.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  Should I just give up on using input type="number" and stick with server-side validation?  Looks like I may have to if IE won't accept a minus sign.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urR8E/)

```
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="field_latitude">Latitude <span>*</span></label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                id="field_latitude"
                                name="waypoint_latitude"
                                min="29.589870336601876"
                                max="29.593170062000013"
                                step="0.000000000000001"
                                pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?"
                                title="This should be a number with up to 15 decimal places.">
                        </div>

                        <div id="frm_field_2_container">
                            <label for="field_longitude">Longitude <span>*</span></label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                id="field_longitude"
                                name="waypoint_longitude"
                                min="-82.238909733700000"
                                max="-82.235952263746870"
                                step="0.000000000000001"
                                pattern="[\-][0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?"
                                title="This should be a number with up to 15 decimal places.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you check your browsers support these features? See [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-number-min.html)

Comment: It appears that all recent browsers on the HTML5Test.com list support min, max, step, field validation and value sanitization... except Firefox (FF mobile supports them but FF desktop does not).  Well that explains why FF does not validate properly.  Why IE 11 does not seem to validate properly is still a mystery to me.  IE's handling of the minus sign is particularly confounding because the minus sign passes the regex validation but it seems that IE treats the minus sign as text and not a number sign.